# Compiling assembly code with gcc for STM32

Tags: assembly, gcc, microcontroller, gcc-warning

GCC was not able to compile the following assembly code for the STM32 microcontroller. The programm should flash the onboard LED of the STM32 "Blue Pill".

```
        .section .text
        .syntax unified
        .thumb

start:
        ldr r0, =0x48000401  ; Load address of GPIOC_ODR register into R0
loop:
        ldr r1, [r0]         ; Load value of GPIOC_ODR register into R1
        eor r1, r1, #0x2000 ; Toggle bit 13 of R1 (GPIOC_ODR_ODR13)
        str r1, [r0]         ; Store value back to GPIOC_ODR register
        mov r1, #5000000    ; Load delay value into R1
delay:
        sub r1, r1, #1       ; Decrement R1
        cmp r1, #0           ; Compare R1 to 0
        bne delay            ; If not zero, loop again
        b loop               ; Loop back to the beginning
```

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb main.s
```

```
GCC issues these problems:
main.s: Assembler messages:
main.s:6: Error: bad instruction `load address of GPIOC_ODR register into R0'
main.s:8: Error: bad instruction `load value of GPIOC_ODR register into R1'
main.s:9: Error: bad instruction `toggle bit 13 of R1(GPIOC_ODR_ODR13)'
main.s:10: Error: bad instruction `store value back to GPIOC_ODR register'
main.s:11: Error: bad instruction `load delay value into R1'
main.s:13: Error: bad instruction `decrement R1'
main.s:14: Error: bad instruction `compare R1 to 0'
main.s:15: Error: bad instruction `if not zero,loop again'
main.s:16: Error: bad instruction `loop back to the beginning'
main.s:11: Error: invalid constant (4c4b40) after fixup
```

I do not understand, why GCC is not realizing, that these parts of the code are commented out.

Comment: The comment character on ARM is `@` not `;`.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. I have already tried to compile a much simpler program to investigate whether the compiler is working correctly:
`
.syntax  unified
.cpu  cortex-m3
.thumb

.word  0x20000400
.word  0x080000ed
.space  0xe4

nop   @  Nichts tun  b . @ Endlosschleife _

`
The error seems to have been resolved, but now the compiler produces the following message.
I was unable to identify the problem that occurred, even after doing some research about it.

Comment: `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/crt0.o: in function `_mainCRTStartup':
/build/newlib-pB30de/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libgloss

Comment: /arm/semihv2m/../../../../../../../../libgloss/arm/crt0.S:545: undefined reference to `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
/build/newlib-pB30de/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7-m/nofp/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:64: undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: That is a different question for which you should open a new question.  Review the tutorial you are following for the correct instructions and symbol names.

Comment: Not every assembler uses the same comment character unfortunately. It's not standardized like C.